# why is form1.hide and unload form1 doing nothing

Tags: forms, vba, hide

can someone explain to me why .hide and unload form is doing nothing? neither one of them by themselves do anything at all. 
the ultimate goal is to display form1, run a bunch of code, then close form1, and display form2.

```
Sub test()
    loadingForm.Show
    loadingForm.Hide
    Unload loadingForm
    'why doesnt either of those do anything???
End Sub
```

Comment: Because those two `loadingForm.hide` and `Unload loadingForm` are not called until you exit out of your `loadingForm`. The code "pauses" execution at `loadingForm.Show` and does not allow another code to run until the userform is closed. You should handle the `Me.Hide` from the `userform's` code behind and `Unload` the form when you have exited out of it therefore further down in your standard module.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by any of this: You should handle the Me.Hide from the userform's code behind and Unload the form when you have exited out of it therefore further down in your standard module.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for the `showmodal` property of the UserForm is `True`.

This is the cause that no other code is running unless Userform1 is closed.

Setting this property to `False` together with the `Show` method should solve your problem:

```
Sub test()
   loadingForm.Show False  '<--- add this parameter

   'insert additional code you want to run here

   loadingForm.Hide
   Unload loadingForm
End Sub
```